# Import CSV file and convert it as a struct using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, csv, struct

I am trying to input file CSV and convert it as struct in matlab.

This is the sample "file_1.csv":
[image]

and "file_6.csv":
[image]

If you take a look at those files, both of them has similar structure, even the content data are different.

To convert the CSV files to struct I am using matlab by using this code:

```
filedir = '/Users/';
files1 = dir(fullfile(filedir, '*.csv'));
numFiles1 = length(files1);

for i = 1 : numFiles1
    patient_1(i).files=importdata(fullfile(filedir,files1(i).name)); % loads data

    %check the in struct patient_1, all of them already success convert to struct
    if (isstruct(patient_1(i).files) ~= 1) 
        % check the number of header of the certain cell file
        % if not convert cell array to struct array

    end
end
```

After I run the code, as you can see on the screenshot below file_1.csv (row 1) succeed convert to the struct type (1x1 struct),
[image: content of patient_1 struct]

with this content of struct file_1:
[image: patient_1(1).files]

But, the file_6.csv (row 6), just convert to "cell", which should convert to "struct":
[image: content of patient_1 struct]

According to that, anyone knows why is this happen? And how to convert it to struct so, the all structure files will same with files_1/other files that already success convert from CSV files to struct?

Comment: If you wish to read a .CSV file for converting to a table, you should read the file using [readtable](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html), and then convert the table to a struct with [table2struct](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table2struct.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for the idea, I have tried it, and it works, but in the other hand, I miss the "first row" of each file once I convert from CSV file to "table" using "readtable". How can I convert it to the table, with still involve the first row? @pkpkpk

Comment: You are welcome. You must specify `ReadVariableNames` as false to prevent that happening. Try calling the function with: `readtable('myfile.csv','ReadVariableNames',false)`

Comment: for additional: the "first row" now has putted on the top most table (I have put on drive) @pkpkpk is there any way how to put not on the top-most table but still involve on the first row?